# WordPress, Swipebox - iPhone bottom menu covering close button

Tags: iphone, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I am using Swipebox through the responsive lightbox plug-in and the bar with close button at the bottom gets covered by the iPhone bottom nav so you can't close the enlargements. I tried adding padding in css, but it doesn't seem to work. I love the way that swipebox works and looks, but it may not be an option for me if you can't close the enlargements on the iPhone.

When you touch the bottom area on iPhone it evokes this bottom iPhone nag which covers the swipebox close button. I would think the solution would be to either swap the top caption bar of the swipe box with the bottom bar that closes it, or to move the bottom bar up so it would not be covered. If I switch from landscape to portrait a couple of times it does move upon it's own. I have no idea why.

When I test the jQuery plugin at the swipebox site it does the same thing. So I am asking if anyone has modified this successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have at least a quick and dirty approach that is ok for the moment.
I set in the css at #swipebox-overlay height: 101%; overflow:scroll;
and in the js at 
$('body').bind('touchstart', function(e){
window.scrollTo(0,1); ....

thats far from being perfect but works for me at the moment for an urgent project...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on android. To puch the bar up to display above the buttons, just edit swipebox.css to the following:

```
#swipebox-action.visible-bars {
  //bottom: 0px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#swipebox-action.force-visible-bars {
  //bottom: 0px!important;
  bottom: 50px!important;
}
```

That did the trick for me.